# Unity playfab problems I need to export to playfab but how to do if unity does not load the scripts because it has errors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Unity playfab problems I need to export to playfab but how to do if unity does not load the scripts because it has errors? could someone help me i'm new to unity and i'm having difficulties with the problem described above. any help is welcome.

I tried it in many ways, in fact I have been trying it for 2 days but without any success I always face this problem in all the ways I try to do

[image]

PLayfabMonetizationExplorer code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
#if UNITY_PURCHASING && UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEngine.Purchasing;
#endif
using LitJson;

public class PlayfabMonetizationExporter : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameInstance gameInstance;
    public MonetizationManager monetizationManager;

    [Header("Catalog")]
    public string exportingCatalogVersion = "Catalog-1";

#if UNITY_EDITOR
    [ContextMenu("Export Catalog")]
    public void ExportCatalog()
    {
        var allItems = gameInstance.GetAllItems();
        var allBundles = monetizationManager.products;
        var catalogItems = new Dictionary<string, CatalogItem>();
        foreach (var item in allItems)
        {
            var virtualCurrencyPrices = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.price.id))
                virtualCurrencyPrices[item.price.id] = item.price.amount;
            foreach (var price in item.prices)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(price.id))
                    virtualCurrencyPrices[price.id] = price.amount;
            }
            catalogItems[item.GetId()] = new CatalogItem()
            {
                ItemId = item.GetId(),
                CatalogVersion = exportingCatalogVersion,
                DisplayName = item.GetTitle(),
                Description = item.GetDescription(),
                VirtualCurrencyPrices = virtualCurrencyPrices,
                Consumable = new CatalogConsumable(),
                Bundle = new CatalogBundle(),
            };
        }

        var iapCatalog = ProductCatalog.LoadDefaultCatalog();
        var iapCatalogDict = new Dictionary<string, ProductCatalogItem>();
        foreach (var product in iapCatalog.allProducts)
        {
            iapCatalogDict[product.id] = product;
        }

        ProductCatalogItem tempIAPItem;
        foreach (var bundle in allBundles)
        {
            var virtualCurrencyPrices = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            virtualCurrencyPrices.Add("RM", 0); // TODO: SET USD PRICE
            var itemIds = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in bundle.items)
            {
                itemIds.Add(item.GetId());
            }
            var rewardCurrencies = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            foreach (var currency in bundle.currencies)
            {
                rewardCurrencies[currency.id] = currency.amount;
            }

            if (iapCatalogDict.TryGetValue(bundle.GetId(), out tempIAPItem))
            {
                // Google play
                catalogItems[tempIAPItem.GetStoreID(GooglePlay.Name)] = new CatalogItem()
                {
                    ItemId = tempIAPItem.GetStoreID(GooglePlay.Name),
                    CatalogVersion = exportingCatalogVersion,
                    DisplayName = bundle.GetTitle(),
                    Description = bundle.GetDescription(),
                    VirtualCurrencyPrices = virtualCurrencyPrices,
                    Consumable = new CatalogConsumable()
                    {
                        UsagePeriod = 3,
                    },
                    Bundle = new CatalogBundle()
                    {
                        BundledItems = itemIds,
                        BundledVirtualCurrencies = rewardCurrencies,
                    }
                };
                // Apple appstore
                catalogItems[tempIAPItem.GetStoreID(AppleAppStore.Name)] = new CatalogItem()
                {
                    ItemId = tempIAPItem.GetStoreID(AppleAppStore.Name),
                    CatalogVersion = exportingCatalogVersion,
                    DisplayName = bundle.GetTitle(),
                    Description = bundle.GetDescription(),
                    VirtualCurrencyPrices = virtualCurrencyPrices,
                    Consumable = new CatalogConsumable()
                    {
                        UsagePeriod = 3,
                    },
                    Bundle = new CatalogBundle()
                    {
                        BundledItems = itemIds,
                        BundledVirtualCurrencies = rewardCurrencies,
                    }
                };
            }
        }

        var dropTables = new List<DropTableItem>();

        var catalog = new PlayfabCatalog()
        {
            CatalogVersion = exportingCatalogVersion,
            Catalog = new List<CatalogItem>(catalogItems.Values),
            DropTables = dropTables,
        };
        var json = JsonMapper.ToJson(catalog);
        var path = EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel("Export Catalog", Application.dataPath, "CATALOG", "json");
        if (path.Length > 0)
            File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }

    [ContextMenu("Export Currencies")]
    public void ExportCurrencies()
    {
        var currencies = new List<PlayfabCurrency>();
        foreach (var currency in monetizationManager.currencies)
        {
            var code = currency.id;
            var name = currency.name;
            var startAmount = currency.startAmount;
            currencies.Add(new PlayfabCurrency()
            {
                CurrencyCode = code,
                DisplayName = name,
                InitialDeposit = startAmount,
                RechargeRate = 0,
                RechargeMax = 0,
                CurrencyCodeFull = code + " (" + name + ")",
            });
        }
        var json = JsonMapper.ToJson(currencies);
        var path = EditorUtility.SaveFilePanel("Export Currencies", Application.dataPath, "CURRENCIES", "json");
        if (path.Length > 0)
            File.WriteAllText(path, json);
    }
#endif

    [System.Serializable]
    public class PlayfabCurrency
    {
        public string CurrencyCode;     // GE
        public string DisplayName;      // Gem
        public int InitialDeposit;      // 0
        public int RechargeRate;        // 0
        public int RechargeMax;         // 0
        public string CurrencyCodeFull; // GE (Gem)
        public string GameManagerClassMetadata;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class PlayfabCatalog
    {
        public string CatalogVersion;
        public List<CatalogItem> Catalog;
        public List<DropTableItem> DropTables;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class CatalogItem
    {
        public string ItemId;
        public string ItemClass;
        public string CatalogVersion;
        public string DisplayName;
        public string Description;
        public Dictionary<string, int> VirtualCurrencyPrices;
        public Dictionary<string, int> RealCurrencyPrices;
        public List<string> Tags;
        public object CustomData;
        public CatalogConsumable Consumable;
        public CatalogContainer Container;
        public CatalogBundle Bundle;
        public bool CanBecomeCharacter;
        public bool IsStackable;
        public bool IsTradable;
        public string ItemImageUrl;
        public bool IsLimitedEdition;
        public int InitialLimitedEditionCount;
        public object ActivatedMembership;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class CatalogConsumable
    {
        public int? UsageCount;
        public int? UsagePeriod;
        public string UsagePeriodGroup;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class CatalogContainer
    {
        public string KeyItemId;
        public List<string> ItemContents;
        public List<string> ResultTableContents; // Drop tables
        public Dictionary<string, int> VirtualCurrencyContents;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class CatalogBundle
    {
        public List<string> BundledItems;
        public List<string> BundledResultTables; // Drop tables
        public Dictionary<string, int> BundledVirtualCurrencies;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class DropTableItem
    {
        public string TableId;
        public List<DropTableItemNode> Nodes;
    }

    [System.Serializable]
    public class DropTableItemNode
    {
        public string ResultItemType = "ItemId";
        public string ResultItem;
        public int Weight;
    }
}
```

Comment: If a downloaded Asset causes problems it is often because it is not made for that version or there are missing Assets which this one is based on. Have a look at this.

Comment: yes, adding to @AtLeastVision, have you tried changing the .net api version? Lots of newer assets are made for .net 4 but unity projects often default to .net 2. You can check in the project's player settings. Also, you might be missing packages. Those errors look like they expect apple store to be in your project. Did you make sure the apple store package is installed?